# Collapsed Table Row is not Expanding on button click

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table that is being populated from PHP.  I have a hidden row that gives details about the item in the row above.  The idea is that clicking the details button will open the collapsed row.  The function is called and the element ID passed, verified by an alert message.  The problem is that the code is not changing the visibility property.  Any ideas?

```
for ($i = 0; $i<$rows; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $detail = htmlspecialchars($row['CommonName']);
                
    echo '<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['CommonName']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['ScientificName']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['DateSown']) . '</td>';
    echo '<td><button name="expDeets" onclick="showDeets(\''. $i .'Deets\');">See Details</button></td></tr>';   
    echo '<tr id="' . $i . 'Deets" style="visibility:collapse"><td>Environment: ' . 
        htmlspecialchars($row['type']) . '<br /><br /> How Obtained: ' . 
        htmlspecialchars($row['obtained']) . '<br /><br />Watering Instructions: ' . 
        htmlspecialchars($row['WaterInstr']) . '</td></tr>';  
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function showDeets(theDeets) { 
  alert("The details name =" + theDeets);
  document.getElementByID(theDeets).style.visibility="initial";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document.getElementByID(). should be document.getElementById().

Use Id not ID

```
function showDeets(theDeets) { 
alert("The details name theDeets");
document.getElementById("deets").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

note, I have used visible but I think "initial" will work.

I have made a quick JSbin for you

https://jsbin.com/xopixipeyu/1/edit?html,js,output

Somehow I also think that your argument won't work as you use "$i . Deets" for the argument and then in your JS "theDeets" (maybe you have that under control)

Comment: Thanks for catching that capitalization typo. I so hate those!  The . $i . ... works because it is in php tags and creates the I’d name for the element. I verified that with the alert. Will have to try the typo and see if that was it.

Comment: Okay, yes of course the correct value would be passed into the JS function. Typos happen to the best of us, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `initial` value *is* `collapse`. In order to make the row visible, you want to set `visibility: visible`. In either case, the `visibility` CSS property will not affect the layout of the page, meaning `hidden` and `collapse` often have different impact than expected.

If you want to create the effect of hiding/showing the row entirely, the CSS property you want is `display`.

```
function showDeets(theDeets) { 
  alert("The details name =" + theDeets);
  document.getElementByID(theDeets).style.display="none";
}
```

If you then wanted to hide it again, you could use either `initial` or (personally, I try to avoid depending on `initial`), `table-row`:

```
function hideDeets(theDeets) {
  document.getElementByID(theDeets).style.display="table-row";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The problem ended up being a capitalization error, but I did use your suggestion...makes for a much nicer appearance.